# Does it make sense to 'lift' an obligation?

Tags: verbs, semantics

I want to say that an obligation that was present previously has been removed in a new approach. Can I say that in the new approach, the obligation has been lifted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While on cursory reading Centaurus' answer did seem fair to me, on second thoughts I feel you should be able to say "an obligation has been lifted". This is for the following reasons:

Centaur pointed out - 
"lift (verb) To revoke by taking back;"
and the correct usage
"the Security Council decided to lift all sanctions against Iran".

If you consider this meaning of **obligation** - "A social, legal, or moral requirement, such as a duty, contract, or promise, that compels one to follow or avoid a particular course of action.", it sort of falls into the same bag of words as **sanction**  -  "The penalty for noncompliance with a law or legal order"

Both need to be, in a sense, dutifully fulfilled. So, I would say you should be able to say **"obligation has been lifted"** if you are indeed talking about it in the way of a rule that needs to be obeyed.

(All definitions coming from thefreedictionary)

Answer (score 1):

You can say that **"the burden of an obligation has been lifted"**, just as we say that **"the Security Council decided to lift all sanctions against Iran".**

> - lift (verb) To revoke by taking back; rescind [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lift)

Comment: I think I agree with this. That is I do if you are saying that a phrase such as, 'the burden of' is a necessary addition.

Comment: Although the metaphor might be considered dead, it's the 'lifting of a [heavy] burden/load' metaphor. The meaning of 'lift' has broadened to include the removal of just about any restriction / imposition / hardship / low mood ...

Comment: Having *burden of an* in the sentence is unnecessary and redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd be more likely to say "the obligation has been *removed*", but "lifted" is particularly appropriate if it's a troublesome obligation.

Answer (score 0):

> in the new approach, the obligation has been *lifted*

Better:

The new approach has *obviated* the need for ...

OR

The new approach has *rendered ... unnecessary*